# how to see iphone logging (NSLog) after app restart?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, nslog

How could I view iphone logging (eg NSLog) after app restart?

I'm interested in the answer both for using the (a) simulator and (b) an IOS device.

Background - In this case I have some issues no doubt in my code with how the application is supposed to launch, get previous state, and goto the controller/view it was at prior to it being terminated.  Hence I want to see the logging as it starts up.

Comment: for device you can use Organizer tool available in XCode(your device should be connected with system).

Comment: ok - yes I see now how to do this for the device - thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For seeing device logs, you can use **Organizer** tool available in **XCode**(your device should be connected with system).

For simulator you will have to re-run application from **XCode**.

Thanks,

Comment: Ravin - is re-running the application from Xcode actual the same as starting the application from within the simulator after killing it?

Comment: Yes, restarting asks you if the currrently running application should be quit and that's like exit(0) i.e. applicationWillResignActive won't be called. The same applies to the device.